# Content preview is not available in Salesforce

Tags: content

I have uploaded a .zip file as a content in Salesforce.com. File size is 8.08MB.
The preview of file is not available.

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? The files within the zip? As far I know the Content preview only supports certain file types - mostly images and the Office extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran out of characters in my comment, these are the supported files types in preview:

> The content details page provides document details at a glance,
>   including document title, author, description, tags, libraries,
>   comments, votes, versions, subscribers, and downloads. If the document
>   is a Microsoft PowerPoint, Word, Excel, or Adobe® PDF file, you can
>   preview the entire file in your browser without downloading it. Some
>   Microsoft Office 2007 features don't display correctly in previews.
>   Copy-protected PDFs can't be previewed.

Taken from:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_about.htm&language=en_US