# How to get a preview link for a video stored in Files object in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, lightning

I have uploaded a file in Salesforce files. After that, I took its shareable link.[image: Salesforce Files]

When I am running this URL on the browser I am not getting a preview of my file.[image: Preview not available]

Can you please tell me how to get a preview link on Salesforce since we need to add a link in video tag to preview it on our portal in Salesforce?

Comment: it looks that also your standard salesforce page does not open this file in preview mode - maybe this file is not supported - this should work on supported files, try first simple pdf file and then see other formats

Comment: Any luck, we have same problem with simple jpeg files?

Answer (score 2):

Content Preview window provided by Salesforce only works for limited filetypes

> The content details page provides document details at a glance, including document title, author, description, tags, libraries, comments, votes, versions, subscribers, and downloads. If the document is a Microsoft PowerPoint, Word, Excel, or Adobe® PDF file, you can preview the entire file in your browser without downloading it. Some aspects of files may not be displayed in previews. Copy-protected PDFs can't be previewed.

Taken from: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_about.htm&type=5

@Girbot answered this first on an another [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/53840/59555).

However, there's an idea open in Trailblazer community to extend the preview support to video files. The idea has been open for 10 years now so maybe we cannot expect much but consider voting as it may help sometime in future.

Idea Link: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpVPAA0